# Автосумма значений текстбоксов в PHP

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть 3 текстбокса, name которых text_01, text_02, text_03. В text_01, text_02 можно вводить только цифры (вот до сюда у меня вопросов нет)

text_03 имеет `readonly="true"`. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при вводе циферок в text_01, text_02 в text_03 автоматически (без нажатия доп ссылок/кнопок) value было равно сумме text_01 и text_02?

p.s. Могу быть не прав, т.к. задаю вопрос, но, думаю, истина где-то около команды onClick, но вот где именно не пойму 8-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте инпутам id аналогично их именам и тогда:

```
var i1 = document.getElementById('text_01');
var i2 = document.getElementById('text_02');
var i3 = document.getElementById('text_03');
i1.onkeyup = i2.onkeyup = function(){
    i3.value = (~~i1.value || 0) + (~~i2.value || 0);
}
```

Comment: да, то, что искал. спасибо огромное!