# Упорядочивание 2 переменных с помощью alltrim

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, Господа! 8-)

Есть 2 переменные:

```
$fio = " ИВаноВ   ивАН   ИваноВич   "; $digit = "  66a66  " ;
```

Можно ли, каким-нибудь способом, по одному символу "процедить" переменные и упорядочить?

p.s.

Скажем в Visual Fox, достаточно функции alltrim(), она уберет лишние пробелы спереди, сзади и в середине до 1-го, а так же сделает первый символ нового слова с заглавной буквы, а все остальные - прописные.

С цифрами единственный способ упорядочивания нашел на данном [сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23010/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-php). В принципе используя это, можно из цифр с буквами оставить только цифры. Но охота что другое.

Comment: Вам нужен аналог alltrim() в php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fio = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $fio); // обрезаем пробелы в середине
$fio = trim($fio); // обрезаем пробелы по краям
$digit = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $digit); // оставляем только цифры или...
$digit = (int) trim($digit); // ...оставляем только цифры слева

$fio = explode(' ', $fio); // режем на слова
for($i = 0, $fl = sizeof($fio); $i < $fl; ++$i){
    $fio[$i] = strtoupper(substr($fio[$i], 0, 1)) . strtolower(substr($fio[$i], 1)); // работаем с регистром букв
}
$fio = implode(' ', $fio); // склеиваем слова
```

**Обновлено 02.08.11**

Comment: выдало ошибку на строке:
for($i = 0, $fl = sizeof($fio); $i < $fl; ++$i){ $fio[$i] = strtoupper(substr($fio, 0, 1)) . strtolower(substr($fio, 1)); }
 - в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Простите, я точно не знаю, но, например, в C++ есть специальные функции для этого.

```
#include "algorythm"

using namespace std;

int main(){  
    string s("dbca");  
    sort(s); // s == "abcd"  
}
```