# Автопометка чекбоксов при заполнененном инпуте

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть страничка, на которой неизвестное ко-во форм, в каждой форме инпут-тексты, и их кол-во не известно. Рядом с некоторыми есть инпут-чекбоксы. (К моему сожалению некоторые формы в таблицах, а некоторые в дивах, что как бы проблемно для JS на мой взгляд)

```
// .. где то, внутри формы. последние 2 цифры у name одинаковые, и назначаются автоматом
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" name="raz15"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ray15"></td>
</tr>   
<tr>    
<td><input type="text" name="raz16"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ray16"></td>
</tr>
```

Можете ли подсказать скрипт, который при заполнении инпут-текста с определенным name, проставлял checked определенному инпут-чекбоксу?

p.s. Сам пытался модернизировать [конструкцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23010/javascript-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-php) которой пользуюсь. К сожалению не смог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
    var n = $(this).attr('name'); // находим name данного инпута
    var d = n.match(/\d+/i)[0]; // находим цифры в name
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name$="'+d+'"]').attr('checked', true); //находим чекбокс с этими цифрами
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/Maten/)

Comment: нет обработки на тот случай, когда ввели данные и стёрли.

Comment: Эмм, ну стереть это я сам могу подумать. В целом код хорош, только у меня почемуто начал помечать каждый 10й чекбокс. Допустим заполняю 2й инпут - отметка идет на 2й, 12й, 22й .. Еще думаю как к этому прикрутить название формы, т.к. написал, что форм на странице несколько, и нэймы просто повторяются

Comment: Это потому что `[name$="'+d+'"]` - ищет все элементы у которых name **заканчивается** на `d`. Переделайте на `[name=ray"'+d+'"]`

Comment: @mantigatos, думаю так лучше вообще не делать, т.к. ставяться вообще все галки http://jsfiddle.net/vSQAY/

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибся в [кавычках](http://jsfiddle.net/vSQAY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотрите вот тут](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event), может быть избыточно, зато городить не надо ничего (и проверку сделать можно). Путь конечно я загнул, можно и упростить, но суть понятна думаю.

```
$('input[type=text]').bind('hastext', function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().$find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});

$('input[type=text]').bind('notext', function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().$find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую