# Пометка чекбоксов рядом с инпутом сразу

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Нелюблю поднимать такие темы, но все же. (Поправил каплю [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189008/javascript-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5) ) . Имея на странице много пар инпутов: пара это input-text, input-checkbox, у которых id заканчивается на одинаковую цифру.

```
// код JS. от ссылки с верху переправил только name на id. код шикарен и работает
<script>
$('input[type="text"]').change(function () {
    var n = $(this).attr('id'); // находим id данного инпута
    var d = n.match(/\d+/i)[0]; // находим цифры в этом id
    $('input[type="checkbox"][id$="'+d+'"]').attr('checked', true); //находим чекбокс с этими цифрами
</script>
```

Собственно, человек заполняет форму, рядом с инпутами проставляются галки, что в инпуте что то есть. Но дело в том, что галка ставиться, после того, после того как поставить курсор в другое место сайта или если после заполнения поля ткнуть куда ни будь мышкой, т.е. скажем если заполнить все поля, то в последнем поле галки не будет (визуально) .

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы галочка ставилась сразу при заполнении инпута заканчивающегося на такуюже цифру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать событие [`keyup`](http://jquery-docs.ru/events/keyup/#overview)

http://jsfiddle.net/vSQAY/2/

Comment: Да, гениально, спасибо огромное. Сейчас опять буду осваивать.